# Why regExp test with flag 'g' return wrong value?

Tags: javascript, regex

The test function of the regular expression returns an invalid value when the 'g' flag is present.

Example:

```
var regExpArh = /(\.rar|\.zip|\.7z)$/gi;
var s = "55.7z";
regExpArh.test(s); // return true
regExpArh.test(s); // return false
regExpArh.test(s); // return true
regExpArh.test(s); // return false
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test()_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag).

> If the regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the lastIndex of the regex. A subsequent use of test() will start the search at the substring of str specified by lastIndex (exec() will also advance the lastIndex property).